# is it possible to use kubectl to get the progress from my running app

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

When submitting a spark job to k8s, I can use kubectl to get the status or the logfile from e.g. the driver pod.

But I didn't found any command how to get the progress of my running app. 
Is it technically not possible to get the progress of my driver or executors?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to compute the progress.
Using   `sparkContext.sc().addSparkListener(new SparkListener() { ... }` give me almost everything to compute the progress. not perfect but goes into the direction which could be enough for me.